# Using multiple classes in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Im learning the basics of java and i cant at all figure out why i cant use a class inside a main method. can someone please tell me where my code went wrong?

main class

---

```
package Base;
    class Game {
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
            Data gameData = new Data();
            gameData.test();
            System.out.println(score);
    }
}
```

---

```
package Base;

public class Data {
    public void test(){
        int score = 100;

    }
}
```

Comment: So you're not even going to mention what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your `main` method is trying to access a local variable of class `Data`. Unlike fields and functions, local variables of other classes are off-limits to classes at the same level of nesting<sup>*</sup>.

In order to fix this problem, make `score` a member variable of `Data`, and add a getter method do access it:

```
public class Data {
    // Declaring score here makes it an instance variable
    private int score;
    // Giving score a getter lets others access the value,
    // but it does not let them set the new score
    public int getScore() { return score; }
    // test() method can be used to set the score to a specific value
    public void test(){
       score = 100;
    }
}
```

Now your `main` method can access `score` from the `Data` class by calling `getScore()`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Data gameData = new Data();
    gameData.test();
    System.out.println(gameData.getScore());
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Nested classes can access final local variables of functions inside of which the instances are created.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `score` is only in scope within the method `test()` in the `Data` class, it doesn't persist after the call to `test()` returns.

Instead of just declaring `score` in `test()` you could return it:

```
public int test() {
    int score = 100;
    return score;
}
```

Then in your main you would store the return from calling `test()`:

```
int score = gameData.test();
```

At which point it will print the score as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For example you could add parameter score to the Data class like this

```
package Base;

public class Data {
    public int score = 0;
    public void test(){
        score = 100;
    }
}
```

Then in the game class:

```
package Base;
    class Game {
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
            Data gameData = new Data();
            gameData.test();
            System.out.println(gameData.score);
    }
}
```